# Java Service Loader Instance Caching

Tags: java, service-provider

Say I have a service:

```
public interface Svc {
    public void init(Config config);
    public void service();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class MySvc implements Svc {
    private Config config = null;
    public void init(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    public void service() {
       if (config == null) {
           System.err.println("null config");
       }
    }
}
```

On application bootstrap, I do:

```
public void bootstrap() {
    //initialise all providers
    serviceLoader.iterator().forEach(svcImpl -> svcImpl.init(config));
}
```

Now, at some other point in my code, I do (with the same `serviceLoader` object):

```
serviceLoader.iterator().forEach(svcImpl -> svcImpl.serve());
```

It prints `null config`

The docs for `iterator` say:

> Caching: The iterator returned by this method first yields all of the
> elements of the provider cache, in the order that they were loaded. It
> then lazily loads and instantiates any remaining service providers,
> adding each one to the cache in turn. If this loader's provider caches
> are cleared by invoking the reload method then existing iterators for
> this service loader should be discarded. The hasNext and next methods
> of the iterator throw ConcurrentModificationException if used after
> the provider cache has been cleared.

I was of the understanding that the iterator could keep returning cached instances of the objects as per the code, but this doesn't seem to be the case here:

```
@Override
public S next() {
    checkReloadCount();
    S next;
    if (index < instantiatedProviders.size()) {
        next = instantiatedProviders.get(index);
    } else {
        next = lookupIterator1.next().get();
        instantiatedProviders.add(next);
    }
    index++;
    return next;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, that code does what the docs claim: it returns the cached and instantiated providers first, and then uses an iterator to look up the rest. A [mre] would help.

Comment: But the providers are instantiated (and cached) during bootstrap, so why is the config null when they're used (via the serve() method)?

Comment: As I said, provide a [mre] we can compile and run to see what happens.

Comment: Sure, composing it right now. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just created a MVP and it is working as expected. The above code was a part of a large codebase, and the problem seems to be somewhere else. I'll dig more and update! Thank you for the quick help regardless :)